# Java: Values updated, but display remains the same

Tags: java, swing, subclass, superclass, listselectionlistener

To start, I must explain a bit of the architecture of the software.
Since a big share of the code is common to another project, I'm currently working on creating a library containing this code, so that it's only written once.

The view that causes me trouble is partially common, so a part of it is now in the library. The common part includes a selectable list, which allows you to print some attributes of the selected Object, and a field that prints the name of the selected Object. This part of the code is in a class that a class in a specific project extends.

In this subclass, I've overridden the listener :

```
@Override
public JList getJListUtilities() {
if (jListUtilities == null) {
    jListUtilities = new JList();
    jListUtilities.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jListUtilities.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
    jListUtilities
        .addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            showUtilityParameters((Utility3) ((JList) e.getSource()).getSelectedValue());               }
        }
        });
}
return jListUtilities;
}
```

And in the method showUtilityParameters(), I modified the value of many parts of the view, so that they match the ones contained in the utility. The code works and the values are modified. But the view still prints the default values (if they are set else they remain empty), except for the name of the object, which is, as I said before, located in the superclass in the library.

Therefore I know that one solution is to declare all the attributes that are modified by showUtilityParameters() in the superclass, but they have nothing to do here, and I can't understand why it does not work with those attributes declared inside the subclass.

So if someone has an idea about why it's behaving like that, I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: In the showUtilityParameter(), can you try to call: revalidate() method of jframe?

Comment: Called it at the end of the function, does not seem to change anything

Comment: Hi! Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can see what's wrong

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/1k9aqiuyxvq2g9c/SSCCE.tar.gz
Here, if you move from PanelManageUtilities to CommonPanelManageUtilities, as public attributes jListInterpolation, jCheckBoxDisableWeight, jCheckBoxDisableElasticity, their values will be correctly updated in the view